# Sign XML with digital signature

Tags: c#, xml, digital-signature, signing

I'm working with some web-service which requires digitally signed XML to be posted via HTTP post request.
They gave me only one file (key.dat) which I should apply to my XML.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look over [here](https://bitbucket.org/anton_gogolev/octalforty-licensing/src/default/src/octalforty.Licensing/LicenseWriter.cs):

```
private static XmlElement GetXmlDigitalSignature(XmlDocument x, AsymmetricAlgorithm key)
{
    var signedXml = new SignedXml(x) { SigningKey = key };
    var reference = new Reference { Uri = "", TransformChain = new TransformChain(), };

    reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());

    signedXml.AddReference(reference);
    signedXml.ComputeSignature();

    return signedXml.GetXml();
}

var signature = GetXmlDigitalSignature(xmlDocument, algorithm);
xmlDocument.FirstChild.AppendChild(xmlDocument.ImportNode(signature, true));
```

Comment: thanks but what I really need is encrypting my key.dat into that AssymmetricAlgorithm key.